# Zxing web decodes Aztec code with base64 padding but 3.4.0 jars produce no barcode found

Tags: zxing

Running the latest java version produces "no barcode found" on an image.

java -cp core-3.4.0.jar:javase-3.4.0.jar:jcommander-1.72.jar:jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar com.google.zxing.client.j2se.CommandLineRunner --try_harder ./IMG.jpg 
file:///home/tom/Projects/mTicketing/zxing_java/./IMG.jpg: No barcode found

However, using the web site https://zxing.org/w/decode and the same image produces:

eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoidGZpLjEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImFjdCI6IjIwMjAtMDQtMjhUMDc6NTc6NDYrMDE6MDAifQ==.eyJkdXIiOiJQVDkwTSIsIm9wIjoiQnVzIEVpcmVhbm4iLCJwciI6IlNpbmdsZSBKb3VybmV5IFRpY2tldCBBZHVsdCIsImZyb20iOiJDbGFyZWNhc3RsZSIsInRvIjoiU2hhbm5vbiBJbmR1c3RyaWFsIEVzdC4iLCJybiI6IjExMjE5IiwiYW4iOiJUb20gQnlybmUiLCJ1dG4iOiI2OTE2NDQzOC02M2RkLTRhY2YtOGZlNS01MjUyMjZmYjhmOTcifQ.Aw_3tELIvR6EqatwR-QxwXC5V1F7Cznr0FfZkl8O8SIYzwcOyJ_coCqBs_2UKMghv0WVNAXikHmavMqLLEaug2H41ElFs48lBz8yEgsCsrbeau2AWDd14KixsfITx3rps9HqMf-aPxb5B3Dw6vYFh2Gnokb1Dhbqfhb1a5j5UJI

However, if the base64 padding is removed from the header in the JWT token ('==') and a QR code generated, the barcode is decoded successfully by both the site and the java code.

I know Base64Url should be used but why is the image successfully decoded by the zxing site and not by the latest jar files?

And why would padding produce an image that is hard to decode?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some more research, I'm pretty sure that the issue I noticed was associated with the length of the data encoded and the resolution of the device displaying the Aztec code and nothing to do with the padding.

As the length of encoded data increases in size, the visual complexity of the Aztec QR code increases. I found that if I used a lower resolution device or deliberately set the screen resolution of a device to low, more complex codes were not reliably decoded.

There was some differences between the ZXING site and the java code but I suspect the site may have a set of decode hints pre-configured.